# MySQL: how does ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP interact with UPDATE triggers?

Tags: mysql, triggers, timestamp, sql-update

If a table uses [`ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html) on a column, and the table also has a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger or an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger, how do those interact? In what order do they run? Is `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` implemented as some kind of trigger? Where is the documentation for this?